# Did Thomas Edison say the "...faith in fiction is a damnable false hope" quote?

Tags: quotes, thomas-edison

Did Thomas Edison say the following quote? :

> To those searching for truth—not the truth of dogma and darkness but the truth brought by reason, search, examination, and inquiry, discipline is required. For faith, as well intentioned as it may be, must be built on facts, not fiction—faith in fiction is a damnable false hope.

It's attributed to him in [multiple places](https://www.google.com/search?q=To%20those%20searching%20for%20truth%20not%20the%20truth%20of%20dogma%20and%20darkness%20but%20the%20truth%20brought%20by%20reason,%20search,%20examination,%20and%20inquiry,%20discipline%20is%20required.%20For%20faith,%20as%20well%20intentioned%20as%20it%20may%20be,%20must%20be%20built%20on%20facts,%20not%20fiction%20faith%20in%20fiction%20is%20a%20damnable%20false%20hope.), but is the quote actually by Thomas Edison?